# Intellisense doesnt list the Gherkin statements which are from assembly reference

Tags: .net, assemblies, specflow, gherkin

Intellisense doesnt list the Gherkin statements which are from assembly reference

Eg: 
In Project A
"Specific.feature"

Project B - included into A as project reference
"Commons.feature"
When I click on "<element>"

In "Specific.feature" file if I do intellisense then I couldnt see [I click on "<element>"]

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a question here?  Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time see the question too, but please make sure that you have the latest version of [SpecFlow](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9915524d-7fb0-43c3-bb3c-a8a14fbd40ee) (since two days or something) and that your assembly with [step definitions is references in the app.config](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies)

Comment: Hi Marcus, I already have 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Vs2010Integration' version of specflow. I added a tag for assembly in App.config and still I could see the problem.